Date-fns addDays function does not add correct number of days
I am currently working with the date-fns library in JavaScript and I am encountering an unexpected behavior when trying to add days to a date. The issue arises in the createComparisonChart function, where the calculateDataForPeriod function is called in two different scopes.
export function createComparisonChart(data) {
  let comparisonChart;

  const dateNow = new Date();

  const date7DaysAgo = dateFns.subDays(dateNow, 7);
  let comparisonDays = 7;
  let currentPeriodData = calculateDataForPeriod(
    data,
    date7DaysAgo,
    comparisonDays
  ); //period is calculated correctly here

  const comparisonButton = document.getElementById("comparison-button");
  comparisonButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const currentStartDateInput = document.getElementById("current-start-date");
    const comparisonDaysInput = document.getElementById("comparison-days");

    const currentStartDate = currentStartDateInput.value
      ? new Date(currentStartDateInput.value)
      : date7DaysAgo;
    comparisonDays = comparisonDaysInput.value
      ? comparisonDaysInput.value
      : comparisonDays;

    currentPeriodData = calculateDataForPeriod(
      data,
      currentStartDate,
      comparisonDays
    ); //period is calculated incorrectly here

    //comparison chart generation code
  });

 //comparison chart generation code
}

function calculateDataForPeriod(data, startDate, comparisonDays) {
  startDate = new Date(startDate);
  const endDate = dateFns.addDays(startDate, comparisonDays);
  //const endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + comparisonDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  //period data calculation code
}

In the first scope, the period is calculated correctly. However, when I click the comparison-button (event listener scope), the period is calculated incorrectly.
For instance, when I try to add 7 days to 23/05/2024, it returns 23/12/2024, 16/05/2024 -> 14/10/2024, 30/05/2024 -> 03/05/2025. When the comparisonDays becomes a two-digit number, the results are even more unexpected. For example, adding 10 days to 30/05/2024 returns 27/07/2032.
This behavior persists even when both of the variables comparisonDays and date7DaysAgo are passed the same in both of the scopes (not from the HTML elements in the second scope). I am using version 3.6.0 of the date-fns library.
I've looked up similar problems but all of them have very small time differences and the reason is the timezone or months being 0 based in JS. I don't see how any of them could be the problem in this case.
new Date(startDate.getTime() + comparisonDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) works as expected.
As I am new to JavaScript, I'm pretty sure this is not a bug and I'm missing something. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Turns out getElementById returns string type and I had to cast it to int. Casting comparisonDaysInput.value to int fixed the issue.
